# MS Access not recognizing new Function

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access 2016, I added the below new function as a VBA module named "ExportMigrationListForSupport"

```
Public Function ExportMigrationListForSupport()

' This Function exports mailboxes to an Excel file which is referenced by support associates for various purposes

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim dbTable As String
Dim xlWorksheetPath As String

xlWorksheetPath = "..\Syneos Health, Inc\SYNH External - Exchange Lync Skype Intune - Exchange Migration Database\Migration List for Support.xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "MigrationListForSupport", xlWorksheetPath, True
ErrorHandlerExit:

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & ";Description: " & Err.Description
Resume ErrorHandlerExit

End Function
```

It is to be invoked from a button that calls the below macro[image]

When the button is clicked, it throws the following error:

[image]

This has me stumped as everything seems to line up as far as naming is concerned.   Any suggestions to resolve this is much appreciated!

Comment: So the module is named the same as the `Sub`?

Comment: Yes.  Same name  ExportMigrationListForSupport

Comment: Normally that's a bad practice. Not an Access guy so not sure if this is an exception.

Comment: Unrelated, but since you have the method in VBA, why don't you call it directly in the button's `Click()` event handler?

Comment: Good suggestion.   One less macro to deal with.

Comment: And actually, no need to expose the `Click()` event to VBA. Simply type `=ExportMigrationListForSupport()` in cell of Property Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the hint from BigBen, I renamed the module to "Export Migration List For Support" and voila, it eliminated the error.   I would not have thought that the module name would matter much, but anyway, I won't argue with success.

Comment: As a general guideline to avoid name collision, never name standard modules to any sub or functions that underlie it. In fact, give it a general name: `ModuleLibrary`.